# A finite set S satisfying $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists a \in S: \gcd(n,a)=1 \lor a | n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like some help with this question. 
Suppose we have some finite set S satisfying $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists a \in S: \gcd(n,a)=1 \lor a | n$,
 and $1 \notin S$. 
Then we're asked to prove that $S$ contains elements $a,b$ (not necessarily distinct) such that $\gcd(a,b)$ is prime.

I've shown that, assuming $S$ contains no primes, $S$ contains a squarefree element. I've found some things but nothing conclusive. Any help?

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot to say 1 isn't in it

Comment: Is the requirement that $a, b \neq 1$, but $\gcd(a, b)$ must equal $1$, or a prime?

Comment: Your rewrite doesn't seem to be consistent with your initial title.  If the title question is what you want to ask, then include it in the body of your post, and explain how, $S$ a finite set, $n\in \mathbb N$, $\exists a\in S$, such, either $\gcd(n, a) = 1, or $a\mid n$ meshes with your current body.

Comment: I edited it. the requirement is that we have $a,b \in S$ such that gcd(a,b) is prime

Comment: Don't delete a question after receiving help. The time other users put into helping you goes largely to waste then (the answers are not just for you). Therefore self-deleting your own answered question is considered rude. Likely you didn't know about this norm, so please don't do it again.

Comment: The answer was false. But yes, understood.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P= \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists a \in S: \gcd(n,a)=1 \lor a | n$
We prove the contrapositive:  If there are no two elements $a,b$ of $S$ such that $\gcd(a,b)$ is prime, $P$ is false.
We can assume that no element in $S$ divides any other because we can remove all that are multiples of any other without affecting the truth of $P$ and without removing one of the pair that has $\gcd(a,b)$ prime.
$S$ cannot contain a prime $p$ because $\gcd(p,p)=p$ is prime
If $S$ contains a prime power $p^n$ for $n \gt 1$, $P$ fails for $p$ unless $S$ also contains $p$, for which see above.
If $S$ contains a number coprime to all other members of $S$, it must have at least two prime factors $p$ and $q$.  Then $p$ violates $P$.
If $S$ contains a number $a$ with only two distinct prime factors, $p,q$, either every element of $S$ has a factor $pq$, in which case $p$ violates $P$, or some number $b$ has no factor $p$.  In that case $a$ and $b$ must both have a factor $q^2$.  Then $pq$ makes $P$ false.
If a number $a$ in $S$ is divisible by $p^2$ for some prime $p$, every other number in $S$ must share at least one prime factor with $a/p$ making $P$ false.
Every number in $S$ has at least three prime factors and shares at least two with every other element of $S$.  Take an element of $S$ and divide it by one of the primes in its factorization.  It still shares at least one prime factor with all other elements of $S$, so $P$ fails.

Comment: Wait, why would $S$ containing a prime power power fail for $p$? Maybe we can find another element which is coprime to $p$.

Comment: you seem to have assumed that no two elements in $P$ are coprime, i disagree

Comment: @Manre:  I have added a line about that.

Comment: I still don't see why S containing a prime power fails for $p$? We can maybe find another element which is coprime to $p$. The criterion does not have to hold for EVERY element in S.

Comment: 'If SS contains a number coprime to all other members of SS, it must have at least two prime factors pp and qq. Then pp violates PP.' Clearly not? Just pick any other element, it's coprime to $p$ so the criterion holds for $p$...